# How to wrap text to fit the DIV length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some contents in a DIV that needs to get wrapped when the DIV width changes. I know that content gets wrapped accordingly but whenever the content has something like this  "***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**" without any space in the middle, the content jumps out of the DIV or DIV width changes to fit the above text. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might help

```
.className{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

1. pre tag
2. property white-space
3. property word-wrap

Here is the code:

```
   pre {
        white-space: pre;           /* CSS 2.0 */
        white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS 2.1 */
        white-space: pre-line;      /* CSS 3.0 */
        white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera 4-6 */
        white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */
        white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
        white-space: -hp-pre-wrap;  /* HP Printers */
        word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5+ */
        }
```

Reference: http://perishablepress.com/wrapping-content/

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the following css:

```
.className{word-wrap:break-word;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
.className{ width:100%; overflow:hidden; }
```

Hope this solve the problem.